# When is a set of vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$ where the $n$th component of each vector is the $(n-1)$st power of some scalar linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n \in \mathbb{C}$. Consider the set of vectors $S = \{x\in \mathbb{C}^n : x = (1, \alpha_i, \alpha^2_i, \dots,\alpha^{n-1}_i),  \ 1\leq i \leq n \ \}$. Under what conditions on $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots , \alpha_n$ is $S$ linearly dependent?

Comment: If and only if $\alpha_i = \alpha_j$ for some $i\ne j$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks, edited

Comment: If it's not clear  why it matters consider a simpler example: (i) If $a\in\Bbb R$ then $\{x\in\Bbb R:x\ge a\}=[a,\infty)$. (ii) Otoh $\{x\in\Bbb R:a\in\Bbb R. x\ge a\}=\Bbb R$. (Because in the second example there's a "such that $a\in\Bbb R$" _inside_ the braces; for any $x$ there is $a$ such that $x\ge a$.)